# Kendo Grid edit command not reaching controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can someone please help with my question:
The edit command in kendo grid isn't reaching my controller.
Am I missing something?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WEEKLY_ORDERS_LINES>()
        .Name("orderDetails_edit" + Model.OrderID)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.ID).Hidden(true);
            columns.Bound(e => e.INGRED_NAME).Title("Ingredient Name").Width(120).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(60);
        })
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("INGRED_NAME").Ascending())
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(p => p.ID).DefaultValue(new Guid());
            model.Field(f => f.INGRED_NAME).Editable(true);
        })
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Food"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Food").Data("additionalInfo"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.Cancel("refreshView"))
)
```

And my controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, WEEKLY_ORDERS_LINES model)
    {
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WEEKLY_FOOD dbFood = _db.WEEKLY_FOOD.Find(model.ID);
            dbFood.INGRED_NAME = model.INGRED_NAME;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        ActionResult a = Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens when you run this in debug?

Comment: I second this ^ comment. It is really hard to reproduce an error, since i don't have your grid controller/source data, etc. I can't really see anything wrong. Try hitting "view in browser" and inspect elements on google chrome. See if you get any errors under the network tab or errors in the console

Comment: Using `.Data("additionalInfo")` will call a JS function, can you post a snippet of this function also? And the structure of your `WEEKLY_ORDERS_LINE` object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a colleague of Rute.

The problem that was ocurring was that the kendo Update was calling other controller and not the right one. This was happening because all the results of the data that were being rendered didn't have an unique identifier.

This unique identifier is now assign to the model.Id and the problem is solved. I understood this after seeing this link http://www.telerik.com/forums/wrong-methods-are-fired.

Thanks for the help.